Can the vision transformer solve object permanence?
Suppose a ball is rolling down an incline as follows:

In the middle of the path, a curtain blocks the camera view of the ball momentarily. Soon the ball reappears after passing behind the curtain.
How will a vision transformer (causal attention over time) applied to a video sequence know whether to draw the black ball or not after it dissapears behind the curtain?
